# How to resolve thin client log on freezing using LDAP + LTSP 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, ldap, ltsp

On Ubuntu 12.04 I have some kind of problem with LTSP and LDAP. Sometimes I can log to the server, but sometimes I can't (window freezes on LDM) log in from the thin client. Everything is OK when I log to the server like the local machine, but I have some kind of problem on thin client.

**pam_mkhomedir.so** creates home directory, but I can't log in because nothing happened - ldm freezes. This problem doesn't exist for "local" users (unix accounts) and on first logged LDAP user. 
It's important to mention that in log I can see nothing special.

Does anybody have a problem with ltsp + ldap on ubuntu 12.04? There wasn't any problem on the previous versions.

When LDM freezes, I get the following in the logs:

```
May 17 11:59:52 bar sshd[6066]: Accepted password for student2 from 192.168.100.22 port 44000 ssh2
May 17 11:59:52 bar sshd[6066]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user student2 by (uid=0)
May 17 12:00:03 bar sshd[6315]: subsystem request for sftp by user student2
```

And nothing else appears for this user.

Comment: I made VirtualBox machine to emulate this problem. You can download it from [this page](http://www.jaworzno.pl:443/ltsp.ova) (md5 sum: **81f414a4f771e67a7f516a0989659e5e**). This's fully-functional LTSP with LDAP service.  Start this server and then, run a several thin clients on the same time. If you try log to the server, probably few thin clients will stuck on LDM  screen.

Administrator:
`ubuntu/ubuntu`
and ldap users `student1...student30 with password student`

Answer (score 0):

Your trouble seem to be a permission/owner trouble or a missing home folder trouble.

Check if the home folder exist and has the correct permissions and owner.

Focus more in LDAP under ubuntu than LTSP. It is more a trouble of LDAP